# Flying saucer pdf with asian character - font in linux

Tags: flying-saucer

I need to know the font that we should be using in flying saucer to print Chinese characters in generated pdf in OS - Unix/Linux.

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me with this??